Simple implication proof does not work as expected in Lean
As elementary as it is, let me ask the following question.
Given the theorem below, how does the proof function express the case the proposition p does not hold?
The implication, interpreted in its classical meaning, should still hold in this case.
variable {p : Prop}

theorem p_implies_p : p → p := (fun x => x)

I surely misunderstand the often mentioned proofs as programs correspondence, the idea of implications represented as functions in particular.
Thanks for any help.

Yes, you misunderstand. :-) This says "if p is true, then p is true". Neither the logical statement or the statement in Lean care (or should care) about the case where p is false.
